# Directory authentication initially succeeded, but no valid profile was found ("get entries" procedure)

Tags: login

I'm using the [wpDirAuth](http://www.gilzow.com/_wpdirauth/) plugin and **some** users cannot log in:

> Directory authentication initially succeeded, but no valid profile was found ("get entries" procedure). [(userPrincipalName=userid@company.int)]

The Google results i found were [not](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-valid-profile-was-found-get-entries-procedure) [very](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wpdirauth-directory-authentication-initially-succeeded-but-no-valid-profile-was-found) [helpful](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wpdirauth-directory-authentication-initially-succeeded-but-no-valid-profile-was-found-g).

The 3 year old comment from the dev indicates that the LDAP profile is incomplete, but the sysadmins don't see a difference with accounts that do work.

What can I do to fix the minority's login issue? Should I manually create a few dozen WordPress accounts for them?

Answer (score 0):

I've activated the [Active Directory Integration](http://blog.ecw.de/wp-ad-integration) plugin to assist with WP account creation, and set the proper Domain Controller (dc.company.int), Base DN (OU=Users,OU=_XXX,DC=company,DC=int), account suffix (@company.int), default email domain (company.com) and login sync settings.

Checking wpDirAuth's settings using the admin account again, i think the problem was "userPrincipalName" in the Account Filter field that defaults to "samAccountName", as users use their account name to log in.

A better solution would be single sign-on like [so](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22865/auto-login-using-active-directory-and-windows-authentication?rq=1) or [so](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/sso-authentication-integration-with-external-directory-service?rq=1).

Answer (score -1):

good day.
before plz check this field:
Bind DN

ххххх

Enter a valid user account/DN to pre-bind with if your LDAP server does not allow anonymous profile searches, or requires a user with specific privileges to search.